# process freeze with exec(), fork() and pipe()

Tags: c, bash, pipe, fork, exec

My goal is to write a program that performs a bash pipe using anonymous pipes in C.

For now I'm testing my function with this command: `ls -l | wc` [EDIT], but the goal is to concatenate multiple pipes or just execute a program without them.

I'm using a main program that calls a function defined in  routines.h header that execute fork and exec:

**Main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "routines.h"

#define READ 0 // for file descriptor index
#define WRITE 1 // for file descriptor index

typedef enum eMode{ // typedef of exec modes
    LEFT_PIPE=0,    // cmd1|... start pipe
    CENTER_PIPE=1,  // cmd1|cmd2|... center pipes
    RIGHT_PIPE=2,   // ...|cmd2  end of the pipe
    NORMAL_COMMAND=3// normal cmd
} Mode; 

int main()
{
    char * commandTest1[]={"ls","-l",NULL};
    char * commandTest2[]={"wc",NULL};

    int pipeFileDesc[2];
    pipe(pipeFileDesc);

    executeCommand(commandTest1,pipeFileDesc[READ],pipeFileDesc[WRITE],LEFT_PIPE);
    executeCommand(commandTest2,pipeFileDesc[READ],pipeFileDesc[WRITE],RIGHT_PIPE);

return 0;
}
```

**executeCommand in Routines.c**

```
int executeCommand(char** args,int inputDataFD,int outputDataFD,int mode){  //inputDataFD is READ PIPE BUFFER
                                                                        //outputDATA is WRITE PIPE BUFFER
    int pid,retCode,status;


    pid=fork(); // fork MONOLITIC: monolitic (father) remains unchanged the son will be transformed in exec of args 


    if(pid==-1){
        perror("Fork Error, for command: ");
        return 1; // TODO: in main read strerror(errno)
    }else{
        if(pid==0){ //son process
            printf("Child process: pid %i, father pid %i , pid fork %i \n",getpid(),getppid(),pid);
        ////////////////////// SETTING OF STDOUT/IN REDIRECTS //////////////////////

            if(mode==LEFT_PIPE){ // nothing to read for the process-> left side of the pipe -> PIPE has NO contet and another pipe is found
                close(inputDataFD);     //close the READ id/channel of the pipe Buffer: !!!! for a process the read side is input !!!!
                dup2(outputDataFD,1);   // redirects stdout on pipe write: fd 1 for every process is STDOUT, dup2 closes the file linked previously by stdout (closes stdout file)
                                        // and assign fd=1 to the file linked by outputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[WRITE]), beacuse of that outputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[WRITE]) 
                                        // is a duplicate and it can be unlinked with close()
                close(outputDataFD);
            }       
            if(mode==CENTER_PIPE){ //repiping: PIPE has contet and another pipe is found
                dup2(inputDataFD,0);    // redirects stdin on pipe READ: fd0 for every process is STDIN, dup2 closes the file linked previously by stdin (closes stdin file)
                                        // and assign the file linked by inputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[READ]) to fd id=0 (where processes get data for input (exstdin)
                                        // beacuse of that inputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[READ]) is a duplicate and it can be unlinked with close()
                close(inputDataFD);

                dup2(outputDataFD,1);   // redirects stdout on pipe write: fd 1 for every process is STDOUT, dup2 closes the file linked previously by stdout (closes stdout file)
                                        // and assign fd=1 to the file linked by outputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[WRITE]), beacuse of that outputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[WRITE]) 
                                        // is a duplicate and it can be unlinked with close()
                close(outputDataFD);                         
            }
            if(mode==RIGHT_PIPE){ //nothing to write for the process-> right side of pipe ->PIPE has contet and NO other pipe is found
                close(outputDataFD); // close the WRITE id/channel of the pipe Buffer: !!! for a process the write side is output !!!!
                dup2(inputDataFD,0);    // redirects stdin on pipe READ: fd0 for every process is STDIN, dup2 closes the file linked previously by stdin (closes stdin file)
                                        // and assign the file linked by inputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[READ]) to fd id=0 (where processes get data for input (exstdin)
                                        // beacuse of that inputDataFD (pipeFileDesc[READ]) is a duplicate and it can be unlinked with close()
                close(inputDataFD);

            }
            if(mode==NORMAL_COMMAND){ // non pipes-> no STDOUT/IN redirections -> PIPE has NO contet and NO other pipe is found

            }


            retCode=execvp(args[0],args); // exec command arg[0] with process name arg[0] and arg[1->i] parameters
                                          // stdout of process is redirected onto outputDataFD that is pipeBuffer WRITE side
            if(mode==RIGHT_PIPE) printf("error TWO %s",strerror(errno));


            if(retCode == -1){

                perror("Exec error, unable to execute:");
                return 1; //smthing went wrong same TODO in main read output strerror(errno)

            }

        }else{ //father process
            printf("Parent process: pid %i, pid fork %i \n",getpid(), pid );

            waitpid(pid,&status,0);    // The wait system-call puts the process to sleep and waits for a child-process to end. 
                                       // It then fills in the argument with the exit code of the child-process (if the argument is not NULL).
            perror("\n");
            printf("\nout of wait\n");
            if(WIFEXITED(status)==1){//this macro translate the value int of status in TRUE if child ends normaly and FALSE otherwise
                return WEXITSTATUS(status); //returns to the main the status of the call
            }else{
                printf("wait error\n");
            } 

        }

    }//end else pid==0

}//end executeCommand
```

So my problem is that when executing this file it runs all the way till the `execvp()` of the second call of `executeCommand()`and than the process (the childre one) freezes and appears to be in sleeping mode.

Removing the wait statement helps but the output is wrong....could it be a waiting problem?

Comment: .... of *course* the waiting is the problem!

Comment: You need to run both sides of the pipeline at the same time. You can't execute one, wait for it, then execute the other and wait for that. Also, you need to actually create a pipe, which you currently don't

Comment: But the pipe is shared between the two executeCommand()  and I'm waiting that the command stops the execution and than the control is resumed to main.c

Comment: You need to start both commands concurrently before you start waiting for either or both

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with `bash`, or any other shell.

Comment: @thatotherguy So I have to start `ls -l` in the child and wc in the father? But by doing that I can't concatenate pipes like `ls -l | wc | cat`

Comment: No, you need to create two (or more) child processes.